# Венецианское Гетто — прописная или строчная?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Как нужно писать такие словосочетания, как "венецианское гетто", "римское гетто" и само слово "гетто", когда подразумевается одно из вышеназванных?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как понятие, исторический район - две строчных. Гетто понятие нарицательное. 
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE&all=x

А как исторический факт: Варшавское гетто. Это уже имя собственное, образует единое понятие.

"Гетто" при наличии такого прилагательного всегда со строчной. С заглавной может быть только в особом применении, как условное имя, без топонимического прилагательного.

Answer (score 3):

Я склоняюсь к тому, что в современном состоянии, как архитектурно-исторический памятник, - **Венецианское, Римское гетто**. Это стало неким понятием с таким названием, а не просто указывает некий римский городской квартал.
Сейчас первое гораздо актуальнее, поэтому основное написание - с заглавной первого слова.

Но если речь все же заходит об описании исторических событий (скажем "евреи селились в римском гетто по распоряжению..."), то какие причины считать "римское гетто" чем-то собственным?! В этих случаях полагаю, строчная куда уместнее.

Смущает только одно. Аналог я нашел только один. Кремль. Тоже некогда район города, ставший историко-архитектурным объектом. Так вот во всех справочниках дается только одно написание - "Нижегородский кремль", "Псковский кремль" и т.д. - без всяких оговорок на строчную в прилагательном.

Оставляю этот вопрос частично нерешенным.

Comment: Я хотел ответить что только Венецианское гетто можно писать с большой буквы, потому что оно было самое первое (и было "именованным" местом города) - а остальные уже назывались в честь него. Так рассказывал экскурсовод. Но посмотрел Википедию (нерусскую), и там эта теория отвергается. Так что поддерживаю вас.

Comment: Про Кремль с заглавной буквы: слова "сами" "знаете" и "кто"  - обычные слова и пишутся со строчной буквы. Но соедините их  - и получится "Сами Знаете Кто".  Моя версия: Кремль с заглавной буквы пишется именно потому, что там обитает Сами Знаете Кто,

Comment: Нет, ну это фантазии))). Давайте все-таки хотя бы видимость академического подхода поддерживать. В таких вопросах творческий элемент или отсутсвует вовсе, или сводится к поиску источников. Вопрос о "первородстве" гетто, тем более о СЗК, который в Кремле,  ну никак не может служить основанием для выбора сточная-заглавная. Московский Кремль получил заглавную при написании с прилагательным - вот тут да, вариант "самого главного" Кремля не лишен актуальности. Но это все равно никак не сказывается на написании первого слова, прилагательного.

Answer (score 0):

**Венецианское гетто и Римское гетто** (Гетто Рима) - имена собственные, названия городских кварталов (**первое слово** пишется с прописной буквы).

Венецианское гетто – исторический квартал современной Венеции, Римское гетто - некогда существовавший район Рима, где обязаны были проживать римские евреи. (Оно было установлено Папой Римским в 1555 году, а в 1888 году гетто  почти полностью уничтожено).

Если, к примеру,  речь в тексте идет об Римском гетто, то **можно встретить различные варианты**: Римское гетто, также Гетто (собств.) и гетто, римское гетто  (нариц.), римское Гетто (нар. + собств.) например: Папская область прекратила существование 20 сентября 1870, с этим закончилось требование, чтобы евреи жили в Гетто.

Таким образом, **автор в различных ситуациях при описании города выбирает нужное название квартала** (нариц. или собственное).

**Из словаря:** ГЕТТО, неизм.; ср. [итал. ghetto] В средние века в Западной Европе: часть города, выделенная для изолированного проживания евреев. Еврейские г. (также: в Европе при фашизме). / О районе города, в котором живут представители дискриминируемых расовых или религиозных групп. Негритянские г. Католические г.

Comment: Не вижу из чего вы сделали вывод том,  что  "римское гетто" - имя собственное. А ваши рассуждения и примеры - это опять личное творчество? Гетто - общее название городских кварталов. Московская окраина или там "нижегородский спальный район" - заглавную не потребуете?

Comment: ДОСТАЛИ ВЫ МЕНЯ, БЕГЕМОТУС, УХОЖУ С САЙТА. Вас не перевоспитаешь, Вы не способны к дальнейшему обучению и развитию, Вы всё "знаете", а это верный признак деградации личности. Вы  стремитесь уничтожить конкурентов, потому что опасаетесь за свой авторитет, одним словом, Вы безнадежны, поэтому выберите себе другой объект для ваших словесных упражнений и примитивных острот. Развели тут дедовщину, иначе не скажешь, просто какое-то вселенское зло.Так  что  эпоха Грамматических войн завершена (или это были грамматические войны?).